# Intuition Behind for Complex Vector Spaces $ \langle v | Tv \rangle = 0$ for all $v \in V$ implies $T=0$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, complex-numbers

I have seen the mathematical proof for the statement, but intuitively, I know that the real vector space is a subspace of the complex. As such, I incorrectly presume that this theorem should hold, especially when we are talking about real vectors.

Obviously, there must be something different about the real vs complex operators. Why isn't the $90$ rotation matrix considered a valid operator for this problem? I am presuming I have a misunderstanding on the definition of a complex operator...

Any clarification is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The crucial point is the fact that the scalar product is  *Hermitian in complex vector spaces*: linear in the right entry and *anti linear* in the left one.

This fact, assuming $<x,A x> =0$ and  expanding $<x+iy, A(x+iy)>=0$ yields $<x, Ay> -<x, Ay>=0$. That minus sign is fundamental as I am about proving. Expanding $<x+y, A(x+y)>=0$ we also get $<x, Ay> +<x, Ay>=0$. This result *also holds in real vector spaces*, but the former *does not*!

The two conditions together lead to $<x, Ay>=0$. Choosing $x=Ay$, we have $||Ay||^2=0$ for all $y$, which means $A=0$.

In real vector spaces we can also produce direct  couterexamples trivially so that we cannot circumvent the above obstruction (no chances to produce $<x, Ay> -<x, Ay>=0$ from other ways in real vector spaces).  An antisymmetric operator (matrix) satisfies $<x,Ax>=0$ but $A$ is not the zero operator in general.